# How do i change the timer interval according to numericupdown value in real time?

Tags: c#

I have Timer3 tick event inside i set the timer3 interval to the numericupdown value:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
                Image img = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
                trackBar1.Value = _indx;
                label23.Text = _files[_indx].Name;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = img;

                if (iOLd != null)
                    iOLd.Dispose();
                _indx++;

                if (_indx >= _files.Count)
                {
                    _indx = 0;
                    trackBar1.Value = 0;
                }
                timer3.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); 
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

I also did it in the numericupdown valuechanged event:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer3.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
```

The problem is for example i set the numericupdown value while the program is running to 10000 and its moving very slow then i set at once the value to 1 so instead the timer3 interval to take effect once i changed it to 1 its waiting for another cycle of the 10000 value then the timer3 interval is acting as value 1.

What i want to do is when i change the numericupdown from 10000 to 1 it will change rightaway and not wait for another round of the 10000 value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Supposing you are using a Windows.Forms.Timer then you need to stop the Timer before changing the interval then restart it.

```
timer3.Stop();
timer3.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); 
timer3.Start();
```

From MSDN

> Calling Start after you have disabled a Timer by calling Stop will cause the Timer to restart the interrupted interval. If your Timer is set for a 5000-millisecond interval, and you call Stop at around 3000 milliseconds, calling Start will cause the Timer to wait 5000 milliseconds before raising the Tick event.

Answer (score 5):

You have to stop the timer, set the interval, and then restart it.

```
timer3.Enabled = false;
timer3.Interval = ...;
timer3.Enabled = true;
```

There are several timer implementations in .NET framework, so if you're using different timer than I used here (System.Timers.Timer), you have to call Stop() and Start() methods instead of setting Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

stop the timer, set the interval and then restart the timer.
I hope it will work

Comment: I did that but I don't understand why this flow? if I didn't do that what will happen?!

Comment: Sometime peoples just want code, dont want to understand.  but its the life