# How to update a timer.interal in Main.cs from another form called ControlPanel

Tags: c#, timer

I hope you can help. I am trying to update a timer's interval in Main.cs called AutomaticBackupTimer. I have created a form called AdminControlPanel.cs and have three radio button in a group. When one of the three radio button's is selected it updates the interval of AutomaticBackupTimer in Main.cs. How can I update the interval of the timer?

What I have done so far is to create a public long variable called iBackupTimer in AdminControlPanel.cs and the checkedChange property of each radio button updates the variable. When I try to read the variable from Main.cs it returns 0.

Main.cs

```
private void AutomaticBackupTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdminControlPanel controlPanel = new AdminControlPanel();
        MessageBox.Show(controlPanel.iBackupTimer.ToString());
    }
```

AdminControlPanel.cs

```
public long iBackupTimer = 0;

    private void RBTN_Hourly_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iBackupTimer = 1000 * (60 * 60);   //hourly
    }

    private void RBTN_Daily_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iBackupTimer = 1000 * (60 * 60 * 24);   //daily
    }

    private void RBTN_Weekly_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iBackupTimer = 1000 * (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);   //weekly
    }
```

Simon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change the timer interval according to numericupdown value in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625976/how-do-i-change-the-timer-interval-according-to-numericupdown-value-in-real-time)

Comment: It seems that you have shared the less relevant part of your code. Anyway, you need to stop the timer to be able to change the interval. `AutomaticBackupTimer.Stop(); AutomaticBackupTimer.Interval = iBackupTimer; AutomaticBackupTimer.Start();`

Comment: Many thanks that solved it. When I think about it know, it's logical of course. You can't fill a vehicle whilst it is moving.